# The use of ἀπό in Romans 5:14

Tags: greek, romans

Can ἀπό in the sense of Romans 5:14 indicate that before this point, the opposite was true? For example, could this verse be used to make this claim:

> Before Adam, death did not reign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the first clause of Romans 5:14 says this:

> ἀλλὰ ἐβασίλευσεν ὁ θάνατος **ἀπὸ** Ἀδὰμ μέχρι Μωϋσέως = nevertheless,
> [the] death reigned **from** Adam until Moses

Thus, the statement is rather simple - death "reigned" in the period of time between Adam and Moses.

Now, we must be rather careful here - the statement only says that death reigned from Adam to Moses; it says nothing about any other time.  Indeed, after Moses, death still reigns and it will, according to 1 Cor 15:51-55, continue to reign until it is finally conquered by Christ for all at the great resurrection (quoting Isa 25:8).

Thus, nothing can be said, according to Rom 5:14 about the time before Adam.  For that we must turn to other Bible passages.